# “allow to determine” or “allow determining”

Tags: infinitives, gerunds

I think that this is a very basic question, but I would greatly appreciate if someone explains me this:

What is the correct way for the following sentence?

> will allow to determine

or

> will allow determining

Comment: Neither one is a sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not an expert, but i think,

You could use it like,.. "I will allow 'you' to determine the right answers"
or "This will allow 'me in' determining the right answers".

Though using it for dialogues such as "For me, these papers will allow determining the further course of action" seems right.

Anyway you must specify an object for the action to be performed on.